# Hiding the UINavigation Bar corrupts my UICollectionView layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm having a problem with my UICollectionView layout. When I hide the UINavigation Bar the layout of the UICollectionView gets 'corrupted' with the margins between the Cells disappearing. In the image below you can see the margin between Cell 0, 1 and 2 is ok but once I hide the Navigation Bar the margin between Cell 0 and 1 is ok, but the margin between Cell 1 and 2 disappears.

The only way I've been able to resolve this is to reload the data. I was hoping there might be a better way to do this ?

[image: Invalid Layout]

Answer (score 1):

Write down this code line in the ViewDidLoad :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

and it should work perfectly !